# Symfony2: Scale images

Tags: image, symfony

I have an application where you can upload and view images.

For the view I need the images in different resolutions.

There are two ways how to proceed:

1. Scale the images dynamicly with assetics
2. Persist the image in different resolutions when uploaded

For me the 1. would be more comfortable but I am not sure if the performance is ok.

Does anyone have some experience about dynamic resizing with assetics?

Regards

Comment: Or you can use [LiipImaginBundle](https://github.com/liip/LiipImagineBundle/#liipimaginebundle).

Comment: So providing different image version dynamicly is running fast enough for production??

Comment: They will be created when it is needed. Also have the advantage of cache resolver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Avalanche Imagine Bundle](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle) for this task. It allows you to configure filters, and then apply them in your templates.

As per your concern about performance - it's not generating the image for every request - only at first request, and it stores them in cache. You have to handle re-generating (i.e. deleting the cache) manually on entity level though (afaik)